# How do I make the camera aware of the position of the object it is tracking?

Tags: c++, 2d, architecture, camera

I'm making a 2D game with a `Camera` that tracks `GameObject`s (usually the player). At the moment, a `GameObject` holds a `RenderingComponent`.

```
struct GameObject {
  std::shared_ptr<RenderingComponent> renderingComp;
};
```

The `RenderingComponent` holds a `CameraMotionTarget`. The `CameraMotionTarget` is a rectangle represented by a center and half size.

```
using CameraMotionTarget = Math::RectCS<float, Math::Dir::RIGHT, Math::Dir::UP>;

struct RenderingComponent {
  virtual void update() = 0;
  virtual const CameraMotionTarget *getMotionTarget() const = 0;
};

struct RenderingComponentImpl final : RenderingComponent {
  void update() override {
    //modify target and do other stuff      
  }

  const CameraMotionTarget *getMotionTarget() const override {
    return &target;
  }

  CameraMotionTarget target;
};
```

The `CameraMotionTracker` stores a `const CameraMotionTarget *` to the object in the `RenderingComponent` and moves the `Camera` according to the `CameraMotionTarget`.

```
struct CameraMotionTracker {
  glm::vec2 getMotionTargetPos(CameraProps) {
    //calculate the target position of the camera to keep the target
    //well within the window
  }

  const CameraMotionTarget *target;
};

struct Camera {
  void update() {
    const glm::vec2 targetPos = motionTracker.getMotionTargetPos(properties);
    const glm::vec2 newPos = mover.getPos(properties, targetPos);
    properties.pos = newPos;
  }    

  CameraProps properties;
  CameraMotionTracker motionTracker;
  CameraMover mover;
};
```

This gets the job done. When the player moves, the camera moves smoothly to keep the player on the screen. If I wanted this to be safer, I could use an `std::shared_ptr` and an `std::weak_ptr` but that's not why I'm here. The reads and writes to the `CameraMotionTarget` need to be synchronized. This is easy in my single threaded game but what if I wanted more threads? I'd like the `RenderingComponent` to somehow call a function on the `CameraMotionTracker` but I don't know how.

Ideally, the `CameraMotionTracker` should only be aware of a rectangle and the `RenderingComponent` should only need to know that it **can be tracked** and unaware that it **is being tracked**. My current design is decoupled but unsafe. So my question is:

**How do I architect a safe, decoupled, system where a camera tracks a rectangle?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a multithreaded environment, you'll likely have a single physics thread that updates the positions of objects and the player(s). You'll also likely have a rendering thread where the camera exists. The physics thread need not run in lockstep with the rendering thread. (You might want the physics thread to update more frequently to improve collision accuracy, for example.) But if the `CameraMotionTracker` has a pointer to the player, it can directly query it to get the current or last-known position of the player (or whatever the target is).

If that's still too coupled for you, another option is to have some sort of messaging or notification system where the target object sends a message saying it has updated its position and includes the new position (and possibly the old to aid in calculations). Then the `CameraMotionTracker` could listen for notifications from whichever object is the current target. This can still work in a multithreaded environment. This completely decouples the `Camera` from the `CameraMotionTarget`. It also allows there to be multiple listeners if you need that as well. They can all just sign up to receive notifications of changes from the target.

Comment: A messaging system seems pretty heavy weight to me. Maybe I should just stick with my current solution as it gets the job done.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. It could be as simple as a queue that is only accessed by the observer and observee. If they're on different threads you'll probably need a lock, but it doesn't have to be too complicated.